# Get filename of current configuration file

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, remoting

I'd think this would be simple, but I can't find an answer.

I'm using remoting and I want to store the RemotingConfiguration in the app.config. When I call `RemotingConfiguration.Configure` I have to supply the filename where the remoting information resides. So... I need to know the name of the current configuration file.

Currently I'm using this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config"
```

But this only works for windows applications, not for web applications.

Isn't there any class that can supply me with the name of the current config file?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile

Comment: @comecme - Yep, sorry that was a typo.

Comment: that property is not available in netcore

Answer (score 10):

```
using System.Configuration;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
Console.WriteLine(config.FilePath);
```

In the odd case that you have separate configuration files for specific local or roaming users, you can locate those as well using the correct ConfigurationUserLevel. For web applications, use

```
WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I am looking for a simple solution where I don't have to know if the application is a windows app or a web app.

Comment: Actually, ConfigurationManager should work in both cases, assuming you only read-only access to the root-level web.config. I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: Hm. It doesn't work well as I thought. You can use OpenExeConfiguration with the path name override to get at the web.config but it requires having the path to the web site, which kinda defeats the purpose. Forgot I said anything :)