# What is the name of the web role .config file with SDK 2.2

Tags: azure, app-config, azure-web-roles

I have a web role in which I have extended the `RoleEntryPoint` to do some work that is outside of the scope of the web site.  As part of the `RoleEntryPoint.Run()` my code is required to read from the .config using `ConfigurationManager`.

While this is a little unusual, using SDK 1.8 I was able to make this work by ensuring that my package included a [The name of my project].dll.config file.

Now that I have upgraded to SDK 2.2 when I try to use `.AppSettings` or `.GetSection()` the values are always null, which leads me to believe it is unable to find my file.

I have tried deploying a Worker Role and the .config file still follows the same name pattern that I'm currently using.

I have also tried naming the file WaIISHost.exe.config.

I am aware that ideally this configuration should be included in the .csfg file, but my questions is does anyone know what I should be calling my config file?

UPDATE:

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888708/get-filename-of-current-configuration-file), I now know that the name of the config file it is reading from is E:\base\x64\WaIISHost.exe.Config, but I don't know why this has changed or what I can to overide this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much investigation and trial an error I finally have a solution.

The name of the file is still required to be [The name of my project].dll.config, but you need to make sure that this file is in your approot\bin\ directory of your package.

I believe my initial problem was caused by the `Copy to Output Directory` property being changed to `Do Not Copy`, although I'm unsure how this happened.  If you find yourself in a similar situation you can just add a file with the correct name to your project and set the `Copy to Output Directory` to be `Copy Always`.

Once I'd done that however I realised I had another problem.  I needed the .config file to have had the config transformations run over it, which this didn't do.  To fix this I updated the .ccproj file to have the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- The first two of these targets are what is defined in the base SDK 2.2 targets file.  When we upgrade we may need to look reassess this. -->
    <CopyRoleFilesDependsOn>
        CopyWebRoleFiles;
        CopyWorkerRoleFiles;
        CopyWebConfigToBin;
    </CopyRoleFilesDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CopyWebConfigToBin">
    <!-- We need to copy the transformed Web.config to the bin directory so that the RoleEntryPoint has access to the config settings.-->
    <Message Text="Copy %(WebRoleReferences.OutputDir)Web.config tp %(WebRoleReferences.OutputDir)\bin\BackOffice.UI.dll.config" Importance="high" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(WebRoleReferences.OutputDir)Web.config" DestinationFiles="%(WebRoleReferences.OutputDir)bin\[Name of project].dll.config" />
</Target>
```

This adds an extra target which waits until all of the other files have been copied to the appropriate directory and then picks up the web.config and puts a copy in the bin directory with the correct name.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to put the config values into the Azure config file (the `.cscfg`) rather than using the `.config` file? You can read the values from the `cscfg` via the `RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue` static method.

Comment: I'm familiar with the .csfg files, but in this case it is not practical.

Answer (score 0):

This page explained why it's called WaIISHost.exe.Config and where you can put it in your project.
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core/

Like knightpfhor mentioned, you can also use [AssemblyName].dll.config to put these configuration too. It depends on the assembly name of your project, you can check property of your web role project.